# Question regarding addition and subtraction of separate indicator functions

Tags: probability

I'm having a bit of a tough time with one of my probability questions.  Here's what was asked, and the answer:

*Let $S$ = $\{1,2,3\}$. $X=I_{\{1\}}$, $Y=I_{\{2,3\}}$, $Z=I_{\{1,2\}}$, and $W=X-Y+Z$.

a. Compute $W(1)$.

b. Compute $W(2)$.

c. Compute $W(3)$.*

The correct answer for a. is $1$, b. $0$, and c. $0$.

Here's my work:
$W(1) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1 & \mbox{if}
& s \ \epsilon \ \{1\} \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}  
\end{array}\right.$ + $\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1 & \mbox{if}
& s \ \epsilon \ \{2,3\} \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}  
\end{array}\right.$ +  $\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1 & \mbox{if}
& s \ \epsilon \ \{1,2\} \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}  
\end{array}\right.$

$W(1) = 2$
$W(2) = 0$
$W(3) = -1$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Comment: Are you sure? I got a=1, b=0, and c=0 from the solution manual.

Comment: A better way to answer this is to write $X-Y+Z=1_{\{1\}}-(1_{\{2\}}+1_{\{3\}})+(1_{\{1\}}+1_{\{2\}})=21_{\{1\}}-1_{\{3\}}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!